# Using Request.Form in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have a view that is bound to the model (EF using ASP.NET MVC 5) and there are three submit buttons to do 3 different things. I was having trouble debugging my logic based on `Request.Form["button"]` and found that the `Request.Form.Keys[2]` value contained the string that I was testing for with the 3 different buttons, so I started to use that value directly in my controller logic here:

```
// This gets post from 3 actions
// 1. Filter Button to filter the index to just the selected project
// 2. All Button to clear the project filter and show all
// 3. Create New button to create a lesson with the project
//    selected in the dropdown (even if not filtered)

var sRequest = Request.Form.Keys[2];

if (sRequest == "CreateNew")
{
    return RedirectToAction("Create", new { pid = lvm.ProjectFilter });
}

var lessons = db.Lessons
                .Include(l => l.Division)
                .Include(l => l.Project)
                .Include(l => l.People);

if (lvm.ProjectFilter != null && sRequest == "Filter") //user pressed the filter button
{
    lessons = lessons.Where(l => l.Project.ID == lvm.ProjectFilter);
}
else if (sRequest == "ClearFilter") 
    lvm.ProjectFilter = null;
```

This works, but I cannot find any documentation that lets me understand what changes will break my logic.

How is the count of `Keys` derived based on my view structure? It appears that it is a coincidence that I have 3 submit buttons and keys count is 3, but I'm not convinced that my logic will hold up. I did try adding a `string submit` parameter to the controller post method, but this resulted in the view model not being properly returned and the value of submit was always null.

Here is the view markup:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="submit" value="Add New Lesson" id="CreateNew" name="CreateNew" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" name="Filter" id="Filter" style="float:left" class="btn btn-default" />
    <input type="submit" value="All" name="ClearFilter" id="ClearFilter" style="float:right" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope everything is alright. I came across a similar situation and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework/7111222#7111222) helped me.

It's works for me but I thought it was easier to do back in the days of JQuery
hahahhaha

I hope this helps.